# Hyper-V Low Disk Space VM - How to access?

Tags: hyper-v

I have a Hype-V setup which I've found myself supporting with very little real knowledge of the system. On the whole it's been pretty simple, however I've got a bit of a curly problem right now.
One of the VMs has run out of space and paused as a result. The Type is "Dynamically expanding virtual hard disk" which is reporting as being 113Gb with a maximum size of 121Gb (I allocated more space to it, but this didn't change anything).
Looking at the storage, it's got 119GB, 0% free.
The drive that the VM is stored on though has a bunch of free space, but it's all running on a SAN so I don't know how that affects everything.

My question is, is there any way for me to get access to the contents of the virtual drive to delete the huge file my team-mate has accidentally created in there? I can see the big .VHD file on the server, but obviously can't open it. I have no snapshots of this VM, and possibly no backups, and there's some licenced software on there that's a pain in the butt to install, so a plan of action that doesn't start with "Nuke it and start again" would be good.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also mount the VHD using [disk Manager](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/disk-management-how-mount-and-unmount-vhd-images) on the same server.

But, virtual machine guests won't stop because they run out of space on the VM. Chances are you either ran out of space on the physical hard disk or you ran out of ram.  Since you are running from a SAN, you most likely need to allocate more space to the SAN.

Comment: Yeah. I should have mentioned that in my answer. I've never heard of a Hyper-V guest going into a paused state because of low disk space in the guest. My guess is that you're right in that it's a Hyper-V storage issue.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I ended up on a call with our external support and that's basically what we did. Turned the VM off, attached it through Disk Manager (Actions > Attach VHD) and deleted the extra files. My messing around with the space allocation caused some issues when we tried to bring it back up so we also had to extend the disk space, allocate more space on the SAN and then bring it back up again. It's currently going through the boot process and has been now for about 45 minutes, so it may not be completely fixed yet, but it's doing better than previously... (keeping fingers crossed)

Comment: In future I plan to make the C:\ smaller on the VMs but provide a D:\ drive for the users to write data to with notice that users caught writing data to the C: drive will be hung from the outside of the building by their heels as a warning to others. :)

Answer (score 2):

Mount the VHD on another VM (or on the Hyper-V host itself) and clean it up that way.